# retrofit 2, экранирование двойных кавычек

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Имеется строка вида {"asdasd":"adsasd"}.
Формируется данная строка с помощью символа экранирования .
Имеется POST запрос, где в качестве body используется вышеуказанная строка. Проблема в том что в body почему то отображаются все символы экранирования. - {\"asdasd\":\"adsasd\"} Соответственно запрос завершается с ошибкой из за неверного формата данных.  Подскажите в чем причина отображения символов экранирования и как можно это исправить?

```
@POST("userItem/v2/update")
Call<MyResponse> updateItems(@Query("Token") String token, @Body String item);



 executeRequestWithCallback(mSyncApi.updateItems(token,itemJson.toString()), response -> {
        sendMessage(response, action);
    });
```

Comment: покажите как вы формируете и выполняете запрос

Comment: будет лушче, если вы отредактируете вопрос и вставите отформатированный код в тело вопроса.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: мне кажется вы удалили лишнее из кода. вставьте нормальный код, пожалуйста. itemJson и action непонятно откуда взялись. token != Token

Comment: проблема не в токене или action. itemJson это строка полученная из JSONObject. И почему то в запросе вместе с  кавычками добавляется символ экранирования. Никогда не сталкивался с такой магией...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что обычный JSON в виде строки нельзя отправлять (если я не ошибаюсь)

у вас есть 2 пути решения данной проблемы

1. FieldMap

   ```
   @POST("userItem/v2/update")
   Call<MyResponse> updateItems(
       @Query("Token") String token, 
       @FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
   ```

   и вы заполняете fields как

   ```
   Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>(); 
   fields.put("asdasd", "asdasd");
   ```

   и передаете в ваш POST в поле fields
2. Body

   Для этого нужно создать класс c нужными вам полями и заполнить их

   ```
   class MyPostRequestBody  {
   String asdasd; 
    .....  
   }
   @POST("userItem/v2/update")
   Call<MyResponse> updateItems(
       @Query("Token") String token, 
       @Body MyPostRequestBody body);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так `@Body HashMap<String, Object> body`
Где ключ/значение - это `{"asdasd":"adsasd"}`

```
@POST("userItem/v2/update")
Call<MyResponse> updateItems(@Query("Token") String token, @Body HashMap<String, Object> body);
```